# In robot framework how do you to create object of class and call the methods in corresponding class?

Tags: python, network-programming, robotframework

In robot framework how do you to create object of class and call the methods in corresponding class? This is the code snippet.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     A resource file with reusable keywords and variables.
...               Use keywords in this file in testcases directory.
Library           /home/kirti/src/Helper/utilities.py
Library           /home/kirti/src/Helper/config_parser.py
#Library          /home/kirti/qa/src/executor/cleanup.CleanUp
Library           /home/kirti/qa/src/executor/cleanup.py

*** Variables ***
${RESULT}         0

*** Keywords ***
Read Json Config Values
    Log To Console     "Setting up the config values globally"
    config_parser.Json Config Parser
    Import Variables    /home/kirti/src/Helper/variables.py
    Log Variables    INFO

Check Machines Reachability
utilities.Check All Machines Status

Check SNMP Counter
    utilities.Get Snmp    192.178.1.2    PPSessionCount

Call Clean Up
    #${cleanupobj}=     cleanup.create cleanup
    #${name}=     ${cleanupobj.cc()}
    Import Library     /home/kirti/src/executor/cleanup.py
    ${cmp}=    Get library instance    CleanUp
    Log To Console     ${cmp}.__class__.__name__
    #${name}=    Call method    ${cmp}    Create cleanup
    ${name}=    Call method    ${cmp}    cc
    #${name}=    Call method    ${cleanupobj}    env cleanup
    #Log To Console     "${name}"
    #Log Variables    INFO
    utilities.Check All Machines Status
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It is common for questions to have a [mcve]. Your code example sadly does not meet these criteria as it's not complete (python code is missing), not minimal (code comments and other code) and does not provide with the actual response.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way you can achieve the desired result.

Lets take example of demo.py which have class Sample

Sample  class has **init** ,getting_path() as methods

```
class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self,path,device):
            self.device=device
            self.path = path

    def getting_path(self):
            return self.path
```

Lets use these methods in Robotfile

```
*** Settings ***
#in the Library section you reference python class in below format 
# (file.class_name) so file is demo.py and class is Sample 

Library      demo.Sample    ${path}    ${device}    WITH NAME    obj

#path and device are two arguments required by __init__,'obj' will be used to 
#access the methods in python class

Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
${path}    c:
${device}    samsung


*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Test_python_class

*** Keywords ***
Test_python_class

    #with obj you now call the method of python file 
    ${result} =    obj.getting_path

    #if method need any argument , this can be passed like
    #${result} =    obj.getting_path    ${arg1}    ${arg2}
    log to console    ${result}
```

Comment: Can I dynamically create objects? What I'm trying to mean is, I want to create objects with constructor arguments that are not static, I want to make a keyword that creates objects with certain arguments that are not constant all the time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a specific instance of a class you can use

```
${instance} =  obj  arg1
log to console  ${instance.function(args)}
```